# In AC, do Electrons move in perfect Sync with Generator Rotation across the whole distance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electrons, electric-current

While i'm self studying electricity, one interesting topic seemed counterintuitive to me, which is:

When an AC generator connects to a long XX KM length cables; each cycle, the electrons in the cables move forward and backward in sync. (like it's always visually explained in Videos)

Does that mean, the generator rotation cycle impacts electrons even at the furthest point directly at real-time, in perfect sync, some XXX KM away? Inside all homes/businesses connecting to it? Or is there something I'm missing? Seems nearly impossible.

This has been a very confusing concept to grasp, It would help a lot if someone can shed a light on it, or refer to some theoritical concepts explaining it.

Thank you,

Comment: The electromagnetic field carries power and information in the volume around the conducting wires at a speed which depends on the capacitance and inductance between the conductors. You might enjoy [this previous transmission-line question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304837/44126) and links therein.